# What does [install] tag refer to?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Following is the tag wiki excerpt of [install](/questions/tagged/install) tag:

> Installation (or setup) of a program (including drivers, plugins,
>   etc.) is the act of putting the program onto a computer system so that
>   it can be executed.

So, what kind of questions can be tagged under [install](/questions/tagged/install)? [Is this tag about **"actual installations"**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912877/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-windowsxp-virtual)

[image]

Comment: Downvoting is anonymous and here on Meta only means others don't agree with the idea/gist of the post.

Comment: @Sha, so the downvoter didn't agree with the idea _"So, what kind of questions can be created w.r.t install tag?"_? nonsense...

Comment: @AnishaKaul Like downvoters would come and check if there is any comment referring them ;)

Comment: @Singer what I mean is that while downvote on Stack Overflow means "it's a bad/poor question" here on Meta it means disagreeing with the idea behind the question/post while it can still be good and valid post by itself. In this specific case it might be less relevant indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[install](/questions/tagged/install) is **not a good tag** exactly because of this sort of ambiguity.

The best-case usage would probably be for tagging problems with [wix](/questions/tagged/wix) or other installation software: *programming problems surrounding installation*.

Obviously though, it's going to also be used for problems like [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) having an error during installation: *problems installing software used for programming*.

**I'd recommend staying away from hopelessly ambiguous tags like that.**

In the case of your linked question, I retagged with what I felt were more appropriate tags, in particular [gnuwin32](/questions/tagged/gnuwin32) and [command-path](/questions/tagged/command-path) since that was what's really at the root of the problem.

Comment: @AnishaKaul There will always be bad tags.  Some are so useless that they're actually banned, but something like [install] isn't necessarily that bad.  FWIW, as of now at least 2 people think your question was reasonably on topic and voted to reopen, we'll see how it fares.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Fine by me.  Problems installing programming software are somewhat borderline for SO, so don't be surprised if you get more negative feedback in the future.  The relevant question is whether your falls under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" entry in [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the true focus of your question is different than the whole [install](/questions/tagged/install) tag issue you make it out to be. Your question simply seems to be:

> *Why was my question about installation issues with programming software/tools closed, when I think it's perfectly on-topic?*.

I guess I'm not far off in stating that. Especially given your argument about the tag after you were told your question was not programming related. Looking at [your particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912877/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-windowsxp-virtual), there are two possible views. You can either read it as:

- I'm trying to install my development software, but I can't seem to get it to work. How can I solve this?

or

- How do I make an executable reachable by modifying the PATH environment variable?

The first version can be seen as fit for Stack Overflow under "software tools commonly used by programmers". Though you can't be surprised that those who read it as the second version think that it's so basic, and that the programming connection is so thin, that they see it as off-topic or at best fit for Super User.

The whole issue is somewhat of a "where do you draw the line" type situation. I would personally fall into the second group of people, though I can somewhat understand where you are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I almost voted to reopen this. But not quite.

It happens that the OP encountered this problem while installing software meant to be used for programming. That doesn't matter. The problem is that the OP doesn't know how to set the PATH environment variable.

That makes it a question for Superuser.

I would recommend that the OP look on Superuser for questions about the PATH variable. There will be no need to repost this question, as I expect it's a pretty massive duplicate over on Superuser.